# Convert a Pandas DataFrame into a single row DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I've seen similar questions but mine is more direct and abstract.

I have a dataframe with "n" rows, being "n" a small number.We can assume the index is just the row number.
I would like to convert it to just one row.

So for example if I have

```
A,B,C,D,E
---------
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10
11,12,13,14,5
```

I want as a result a dataframe with a single row:

```
A_1,B_1,C_1,D_1,E_1,A_2,B_2_,C_2,D_2,E_2,A_3,B_3,C_3,D_3,E_3
--------------------------
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,5
```

What would be the most idiomatic way to do this in Pandas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's try this, using `stack`, `to_frame`, and T:

```
df.index = df.index + 1
df_out = df.stack()
df_out.index = df_out.index.map('{0[1]}_{0[0]}'.format)
df_out.to_frame().T
```

Output:

```
   A_1  B_1  C_1  D_1  E_1  A_2  B_2  C_2  D_2  E_2  A_3  B_3  C_3  D_3  E_3
0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14    5
```

Comment: This is want @Wen posted right? other than incremeting the index

Comment: @Dark without the swaplevel :)

Comment: I missed that one, though I learnt column mapping from you, you get my vote ;)

Comment: nice for this , :-)

Answer (score 6):

Unstack and map i.e

```
ndf = df.unstack().to_frame().T

ndf.columns = ndf.columns.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format) 

    A_0  A_1  A_2  B_0  B_1  B_2  C_0  C_1  C_2  D_0  D_1  D_2  E_0  E_1  E_2
0    1    6   11    2    7   12    3    8   13    4    9   14    5   10    5
```

In case you want the sorted columns then you can do

```
ndf = df.unstack().to_frame().T.sort_index(1,1)
```

Answer (score 5):

We need `stack` and `swaplevel`

```
df1=df.stack().swaplevel()
df1.index=df1.index.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format) 
df1.to_frame().T
Out[527]: 
   A_0  B_0  C_0  D_0  E_0  A_1  B_1  C_1  D_1  E_1  A_2  B_2  C_2  D_2  E_2
0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14    5
```

Or you can using numpy

```
pd.DataFrame(data=np.concatenate(df.values),index=[m+'_'+str(n) for m,n in zip(df.columns.tolist()*3,np.repeat([1,2,3],df.shape[1]))]).T
Out[551]: 
   A_1  B_1  C_1  D_1  E_1  A_2  B_2  C_2  D_2  E_2  A_3  B_3  C_3  D_3  E_3
0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14    5
```

Comment: I thought of unstack, you went for stack ; )

Comment: @Dark aha, almost same , even we can melt  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Another way using list comprehension -

```
ndf = pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(1, -1)[0]).T
ndf.columns = [j + '_' + str(i) for i in range(1, 4) for j in df.columns]
```

Comment: Your answer is badly written. But, this is the only answer that has what I am looking for `DataFrame().T`. That `.T` is all what I needed to add in my case as I already had a flattened numpy vector array.