# Python from 2D to 1D pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 2D pandas dataframe that looks something like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame( [ [1,2,4, 3], [10,20,30, 12], [4,10,3,7], [8, 31, 23, 5] ], columns = ["A","B","C", "D"], index=["cars","bikes","trains","boats"])
```

What I would need to do is to convert this 2D dataframe not to a list, not to a numpy array but to a 1D dataframe that would have as column headers:
A - cars, B - Cars, C - cars, D - cards, A - bikes, B - bikes, C - bikes, eccetera and the respective value for each combination row/column.
O
I'm not a python expert, probably the output data structure I need is a series. What is important to me is to make sure I won't loose the label of every value, meaning 2 corresponds to row 'cars' and column 'B'.
Is it possible to achieve this without using two loop for?
Thank you

Comment: It's difficult to visualize what you're requesting, can you post a sample output?

Comment: Have you tried `df1.stack()` or `df1.unstack()`. What is your required output format otherwise?

Comment: I have to be honest and I confirm what explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47736022/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-into-a-single-row-dataframe is all I needed. I swear I spent time searching but didn't find that solution. Thank you all.