# Flatten and Shape JSON DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the below JSON string in `data`. I want it to look like the Expected Result Below

```
import json
import pandas as pd

data = [{'useEventValue': True,
  'eventConditions': [{'type': 'CATEGORY',
    'matchType': 'EXACT',
    'expression': 'ABC'},
   {'type': 'ACTION',
    'matchType': 'EXACT',
    'expression': 'DEF'},
   {'type': 'LABEL', 'matchType': 'REGEXP', 'expression': 'GHI|JKL'}]}]
```

Expected Result:

|  | Category_matchType | Category_expression | Action_matchType | Action_expression | Label_matchType | Label_expression |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | EXACT | ABC | EXACT | DEF | REGEXP | GHI|JKL |

What I've Tried:

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47736022/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-into-a-single-row-dataframe) is similar, but I'm not using the index the way the OP is. Following this example, I've tried using [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) and then using various forms of [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html), [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), etc.   But there has to be an easier way!

```
# this bit of code produces the below result where I can start using reshaping functions to get to what I need but it seems messy
df = pd.json_normalize(data, 'eventConditions')
```

|  | type | matchType | expression |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | CATEGORY | EXACT | ABC |
| 1 | ACTION | EXACT | DEF |
| 2 | LABEL | REGEXP | GHI|JKL |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `json_normalize` to read the json data as `pandas` dataframe, then use `stack` followed by `unstack` to reshape the dataframe

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data, 'eventConditions')
df = df.set_index([df.groupby('type').cumcount(), 'type']).stack().unstack([1, 2])
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
```

---

```
  CATEGORY_matchType CATEGORY_expression ACTION_matchType ACTION_expression LABEL_matchType LABEL_expression
0              EXACT                 ABC            EXACT               DEF          REGEXP          GHI|JKL
```

Comment: the `groupby` with `cumcount()` is a nice little trick. would've never thought of that.

Comment: @MattR Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

If your data is not too large in size, you could maybe process the json data first and then create a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

data = [{'useEventValue': True,
  'eventConditions': [{'type': 'CATEGORY',
    'matchType': 'EXACT',
    'expression': 'ABC'},
   {'type': 'ACTION',
    'matchType': 'EXACT',
    'expression': 'DEF'},
   {'type': 'LABEL', 'matchType': 'REGEXP', 'expression': 'GHI|JKL'}]}]

new_data = {}
for i in data:
    for event in i['eventConditions']:
        for key in event.keys():
            if key != 'type':
                col_name = event['type'] + '_' + key
                new_data[col_name] = [event[key]] if col_name not in new_data else new_data[col_name].append(event[key]) 
              
                
df = pd.DataFrame(new_data)
df
```

Just found a way to do it with Pandas only:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data, 'eventConditions')

df = df.melt(id_vars=[('type')])
df['type'] = df['type'] + '_' + df['variable']
df.drop(columns=['variable'], inplace=True)
df.set_index('type', inplace=True)
df = df.T
```