# How do I reformat several columns of a DataFrame into one row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is snippet of the dataframe I am using:

```
    type        date       time      open     close    change  high   low     200ema 50ema
0  sixty-min  2007-06-04  09:00:00  1536.28  1534.71  -0.102  0.000 -0.259     NaN  1522.90
1  sixty-min  2007-06-04  10:00:00  1534.87  1534.79  -0.005  0.109 -0.106     NaN  1523.37
2  sixty-min  2007-06-04  11:00:00  1534.88  1536.08   0.078  0.124 -0.023     NaN  1523.87
3  sixty-min  2007-06-04  12:00:00  1536.21  1537.30   0.071  0.118 -0.036     NaN  1524.39
4  sixty-min  2007-06-04  13:00:00  1537.31  1536.23  -0.070  0.011 -0.130     NaN  1524.86
5  sixty-min  2007-06-04  14:00:00  1536.25  1536.91   0.043  0.096 -0.078     NaN  1525.33
6  sixty-min  2007-06-04  15:00:00  1536.53  1539.10   0.167  0.260  0.000     NaN  1525.87
7  sixty-min  2007-06-04  16:00:00  1539.00  1539.18   0.012  0.012  0.000     NaN  1526.39
8  sixty-min  2007-06-05  09:00:00  1539.12  1533.15  -0.389  0.000 -0.456     NaN  1526.66
9  sixty-min  2007-06-05  10:00:00  1533.16  1534.77   0.105  0.160 -0.178     NaN  1526.97
```

What I would like to do is to compile this dataframe into a dataframe with just one row. It would have the following columns:

```
[ 'date' '60 9 open,'   '60 9 close,'   '60 9 change,'  '60 9 high',    '60 9 low', '60 9 200ema',  '60 9 50ema', 
'60 10 open',   '60 10 close',  '60 10 change', '60 10 high',   '60 10 low',    '60 10 200ema', '60 10 50ema',
'60 11 open',   '60 11 close',  '60 11 change', '60 11 high',   '60 11 low',    '60 11 200ema', '60 11 50ema',
'60 12 open',   '60 12 close',  '60 12 change', '60 12 high',   '60 12 low',    '60 12 200ema', '60 12 50ema',
'60 13 open',   '60 13 close',  '60 13 change', '60 13 high',   '60 13 low',    '60 13 200ema', '60 13 50ema',
'60 14 open',   '60 14 close',  '60 14 change', '60 14 high',   '60 14 low',    '60 14 200ema', '60 14 50ema',
'60 15 open',   '60 15 close',  '60 15 change', '60 15 high',   '60 15 low',    '60 15 200ema', '60 15 50ema',
'60 16 open',   '60 16 close',  '60 16 change', '60 16 high',   '60 16 low',    '60 16 200ema', '60 16 50ema',]
```

The difference would be that there is just one date on the row and no type, and there is a heading based on the data type/ time of each cell.

Comment: check this out, maybe it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47736022/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-into-a-single-row-dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first extract the hour as int and group by date:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.hour
df = df.groupby('date').agg(list)
```

Then for each date concatenate (along column/axis1) dataframes created from each column.
Finally concatenate (along rows/axis0) the dataframes for all dates:

```
df_out = pd.concat([
    pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([row[col]], index=[index],
            columns=[f'60 {h} {col}' for h in row['time']])
        for col in row.index[1:]], axis=1) 
    for index, row in df.iterrows()
])
```

Output:

```
            60 9 open  60 10 open  60 11 open  60 12 open  60 13 open  60 14 open  60 15 open  ...  60 10 50ema  60 11 50ema  60 12 50ema  60 13 50ema  60 14 50ema  60 15 50ema  60 16 50ema
2007-06-04    1536.28     1534.87     1534.88     1536.21     1537.31     1536.25     1536.53  ...      1523.37      1523.87      1524.39      1524.86      1525.33      1525.87      1526.39
2007-06-05    1539.12     1533.16         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  ...      1526.97          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN
```